# При парсинге сайта нет данных

Tags: python, парсер

Парсю, например, страницу http://www.myscore.ru/match/nqD8D0j4/#match-summary.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.myscore.ru/match/nqD8D0j4/#match-summary')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(page.content)
```

В результате при выводе нет необходимых данных с таблиц. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А `page.text` что-то возвращает?

Comment: Выводит, но нет там не все данные

Comment: А что не так с данными? Напишите ожидаемый результат и текущий

Comment: Нет событий по игре. Кто забил гол, кто получил желтую карточку и т.д.

Comment: Например пропарсить только по определенным лигам?
https://fscore.uz/football/tables/england/premier-league

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там и не должно быть этих данных. Посмотрите внутрь кода: все данные в таблицу забираются средствами Javascript. Чтобы вытащить данные, надо повторить запросы к серверу этого сервиса (примерно сюда: "http://d.myscore.ru/x/feed/proxy" и "http://www.myscore.ru/match/nqD8D0j4/") - а затем правильно их разобрать.

Вообще говоря, это не будет идеальным решением, так как сервис в любой момент может поменять формат.

Comment: Если воспользоваться каким-нибудь браузерным движком, например WebKit, то он сам бы выполнил все нужные скрипты и запросы

Comment: Да, WebKit - это один из самых универсальных способов вытащить эти таблицы.

Comment: а на питоне есть какие-нибудь модули для использования браузерных движков? Я знаю QWebKit, входящий в PySide (PyQt4/5)

Comment: Есть [PythonWebKit](http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/)

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю свой пример использующий `QtWebKit` из `PySide`. В примере я загружаю страницу с статистикой и вытаскиваю из нее текст вкладок (`Матч`, `1-й тайм`, `2-й тайм`) и прохожу по таблице `Матч`, вытаскивая из нее все теги `tr`:

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from PySide.QtNetwork import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Чтобы не было проблем запуска компов с прокси:
    QNetworkProxyFactory.setUseSystemConfiguration(True)

    QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

    view = QWebView()
    # view.show()
    view.load('http://www.myscore.ru/match/nqD8D0j4/#match-statistics;0')

    # Ждем пока прогрузится страница
    loop = QEventLoop()
    view.loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()

    doc = view.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
    print(doc.findFirst("#statistics-0-statistic a").toPlainText())
    print(doc.findFirst("#statistics-1-statistic a").toPlainText())
    print(doc.findFirst("#statistics-2-statistic a").toPlainText())

    table = doc.findFirst("#tab-statistics-0-statistic .parts")
    for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
        l, text, r = tr.toPlainText().split('\t')
        print(l, text, r)

    # sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат:

```
Матч
1-й тайм
2-й тайм
50% Владение мячом 50%
9 Удары 15
5 Удары в створ 6
3 Удары мимо 7
1 Блок-но ударов 2
23 Штрафные 10
6 Угловые 9
3 Офсайды 6
29 Вбрасывания 26
5 Сэйвы 5
7 Фолы 19
1 Желтые карточки 3
```

Для установки `PySide` достаточно прописать в консоли: `pip install PySide`

Comment: Не работает с PySide2
from PySide2.QtCore import * => Cannot find reference QtCore